# Standard deviation for adjusted effect size estimates

Tags: r, standard-deviation, effect-size

I am trying to calculate the effect size for a trait adjusted for my set of nuisance variables. My models looks like this:

```
Trait ~ Dx + Age + Sex
```

Where "Trait" is a continuous variable and "Dx" is a binary group membership variable.

I'm using this basic formula to get an effect size estimate:

```
(mean(Trait[which(Dx==0)])-mean(Trait[which(Dx==1)]))/SDpooled
```

but I am mostly interested in the effect size after correcting for `Age` and `Sex`.

I calculated the marginal means (i.e. corrected for Age and Sex) for the `Trait` split by `Dx` group as shown here:  [on page 15, section 7.5 (PDF)](http://www.gmw.rug.nl/~boomsma/apstatdata/ANCOVA_R.pdf)

But I want to know which standard deviation I should use. Is it required to also adjust the pooled standard deviation by the covariates? Is there some better way to get effect size estimates adjusted by a set of nuisance variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to use linear regression with the formula you gave, which provides a standard error (which is equivalent to the standard deviation of the adjusted mean difference).

`lm(trait ~ Dx + Age + Sex)`

If you insist on doing it "by hand", you can take the residuals from a regression of trait on `Age` and `Sex`, and calculate the mean difference according to trait and its standard deviation like this (supposing `Dx` has levels `0` and `1`)

```
resids = resid(lm(trait ~ Age + Sex))
Dx0 = Dx == 0; Dx1 = Dx == 1
mean.diff = mean(resids[Dx1]) - mean(resids[Dx0])
pooled.sd = sqrt(sd(resids[Dx1])^2/length(resids[Dx1])+sd(resids[Dx0])^2/length(resids[Dx0]))
T = mean.diff/pooled.sd
```

using this formula:
[image]

But this involves an unsolved problem in statistics (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behrens%E2%80%93Fisher_problem)). You might observe that the two approaches give very similar results if the explanatory variables are uncorrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can estimate the SD from SE (SD = SE × square root of sample size). Then you can use the SD and the estimated marginal means to estimate the effect size.